# Flink custom partitioner example

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

The use case that I am trying to tackle is as follows:

- We have a data stream flowing in from Kafka
- We would like to guarantee that message/records containing the same value for a particular entity gets processed by the same operator.
- We would like to maintain state on this Operator so that we are able to enrich future messages.

So for example :

- Lets assume that all messages are byte arrays having representing encoded data.
- All messages which have a particular value within the encoded data should be processed by a single operator.
- This is so that when we receive certain special messages that also correspond to the same value these can be stored as state on the Operator (after the partitioner) and can be used to enrich subsequent messages.

Questions:

1. Will a custom partitioner help with this?
2. If not what would be a good solution for this?
3. Can someone share an example of a Custom partitioner in Flink for a Datastream. I was not able to find any complete examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom partitioner would help, but it is not necessary for you case.

You can just extract the grouping value from you messages and use it as grouping-key. Thus, after the sources read the data, you use a `map` to extract the value (eg, *Record -> (groupingValue, Record)* with data types `byte[] -> Tuple2<keyType,byte[]>` if you want to keep the raw message). Afterwards, you can use `.keyBy(0)` and apply whatever operator you want on it. `keyBy` ensures, that all records with the same value in the first field of `Tuple2` are processed by the same operator.

Comment: How will this work in a cluster? Will Flink route messages processed by any node to a single operator on one node? I am also starting to think that  this could be solved by maintaining a global cache across cluster. I am not sure if this is supported by Flink. @Matthias what do you think?

Comment: In a cluster, Flink will redistributed the data to ship all records with the same key to a single machine (that is what `keyBy()` does). On each machine, there will be one or multiple operators/threads (depending on your configuration) processing the records (internally, each operator separates the processing for each key -- so that keys do not interfere -- ie, if you program a custom UDF, you will not see multiple keys in your UDF -- there will be multiple instances of the UDF, ie, one for each key). So you do not do anything -- Flink takes care of it for you.

Comment: Thanks. Also I am wondering what would happen if this machine went down. I am guessing Flink will probably redo this on another node. That will mean that I will be losing state of the operator. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Just use Flink's managed operator state mechanism (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/apis/streaming/state.html). Thus, Flink is able to recover the state, too.

Comment: I just tried the map->Tuple2<Integer, R> -> keyBy(0)-> map. Now I am expecting the instance of the second map is shared among all records grouped by key. However when I set some state on the instance of the 2nd map it is not retained for subsequent records having the same key. Any inputs?

Comment: Not sure why it does not work... I guess, this threads is getting too long -- can you start a new SO question and share your code there (or just extend your question above)?

Comment: I guess I will add another question for this like you suggested.